# O notation algebra

Tags: algorithm, big-o, algebra

I need to prove that (N + 1)(Hn + 0(1)) = NlnN + O(N).

The approximation that Hn = lnN + O(1) was used before.
Just by expanding it.

= N(lnN + O(1)) + O(N) + (lnN + O(1)) + O(1)

= NlnN + O(N) + O(N) + lnN + O(1) + O(1)

we ignore the extra O(N) and constant run times
but what happens to lnN is it because it is asymptotically smaller then NlnN so we can ignore it? 
Not sure if my understanding is completely wrong.

Comment: I think your post and question is related to math! here SO community is for coding and coding problems. So please ask your question in math communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that you have defined an algebra of complexity classes, and know what +, *, and = mean, in which case it's just a matter of applying the axioms (or simple theorems) of this algebra, but if not, you have to be a little more careful with what they mean, otherwise your proof is not really sound.

(N+1)(H(N) + O(1)) is the class of functions that are of the form (N+1)(H(N) + f(N)) where f is O(1), and NlnN + O(N) is the class of functions that are of the form NlnN + g(N) where g is O(N). The equals sign is class equivalence. You'd prove it by saying the first class is a subset of the second class, and vice versa.

Anyway, so now it's clearer what we're actually proving, we can go ahead. I'll prove one direction of equivalence, and leave you to do the (slightly harder) reverse direction.

Suppose we have a function that's of the form (N+1)(H(N) + f(N)) where f is O(1).

Then there's a C such that for large N, (N+1)(H(N) + f(N)) <= (N+1)(H(N)+C).
Similarly, there's a D such that for large N, H(N) <= lnN + D. Putting these two together, we have for large N, (N+1)(H(N) + F(N)) <= (N+1)(lnN + E) (where E=C+D).

This is equal to NlnN + lnN+ (N+1)E. Since lnN + (N+1)E is O(N), we've proved that our function is in NlnN + O(N). Thus (N+1)(H(N)+O(1)) is a subset of NlnN + O(N).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that’s left to prove is that `O(N) + lnN = O(N)`. That should be quite easy - linear function grows faster than logarithm. Just use the definition of big-O for proof.